# JAVA string method

Tags: java, string

I do not understand what the method `fun2` is supposed to do? What is the meaning of the returned string `s`?

**0 <= i < s.length()**

```
public static String fun2(String s, int i)
{
    char value = s.charAt(i);
    while(i>0 && s.charAt(i-1) < value)
    {
        s=s.substring(0,i)+s.charAt(i-1)+s.substring(i+1);
        i=i-1;
    }
    s=s.substring(0,i)+value+s.substring(i+1);
    return s;
}
```

Sometimes it puts the i index in the beginning and and the rest after and sometimes not. Im confused.

Comment: What are you confused by?

Comment: Try approaching this systematically, by carefully selecting your input parameters and making experiments (that print for example when something happens). Asking other people to analyze your homework will not help you in the long run. And please note that there is a special stackexchange site for code puzzles.

Comment: @shmosel. i am confused by "Sometimes it puts the i index in the beginning and and the rest after and sometimes not." as i said.

Comment: Why don't you add few cases you have tested with inputs and the corresponding output?

Comment: When you compare `char` values with `<`, their Unicode values are compared. For lowercase English letters this gives their alphabetical order: `a` is less than `b` etc. The uppercase English letters are less than the lowercase ones, though: `Z` is less than `a`.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's start with you method `fun2`. Your method takes two parameters, a String s and an Integer i. You probably have a main method somewhere to test this method. Let's say you put the String "apple" and the int 1.

Now what this does:

```
char value = s.charAt(i);
```

The char variable `value` equals the character positioned at the index (i). When you count the index on a String you start at position 0. In this case, your `value` would be 'p' since it is at position/index 1.

Then you have a `while` loop.

```
while(i>0 && s.charAt(i-1) < value) {
```

What it does is to run the loop while the variable `i` is greater than 0 AND the position of the character of the String at index `i-1` (which would be 'a' in our case) is lesser than the variable `value` (which is 'p' in our case).

In the loop while:

```
s=s.substring(0,i)+s.charAt(i-1)+s.substring(i+1);
i=i-1;
```

What it does is taking the `String s` from position 0 to position i. In our case it would be from 0 to 1 minus 1 (since the actual index does not count), which means it would be the `char` at position 0 (**a** in our case) + the character at position `i-1` (which is still **a**) + `String s` from position `i+1` (when it doesn't give you an end position, by default it includes every character until the end of the String). In our case it would be "**ple**".

This means that `s` is now equals to "**aaple**"

Then it decrements by 1 the value of i, `i = i-1`. Now if you try to run the loop again, it won't run it because the condition statement will be false (given that i is now equals to 0).

Once you are out of the loop, you have the following:

```
s=s.substring(0,i)+value+s.substring(i+1);
```

Same as explained above, this will give you a substring from 0 to i on you String "**aaple**" which would be nothing since you can`t get position (0,0) and then adding the`value` which is still 'p' and then adding the substring of i+1 which would give "**aple**". The value of your string is now "**paple**".

```
return s;
```

When you build a method if it's not a `void` type it will have a return type, in our case `String`. It is mandatory to return the return type at the end of the method. What it means is that the method returns the String s ("**paple**").

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Nice explanation, however for `System.out.println(fun2("apple", 1));` I get `paple`

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I edited it. s.substring(0,0) doesn`t return a char. So indeed, the result would be paple

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know how while loops work, and how substring and charAt methods work. Describing the process of the code execution doesn't help in anyway. I don't understand what is the meaning of the return string s.

Comment: Ok check the edit, I added information about the return at the end. If it answers your question than mark this as the answer please.